# how to numerically divide two unequal vector in R

Tags: r

I have a formula as:

[image]

in the above formula Delta(G) is a vector of 300 rows and 2 columns (Energy vs. distance) and D(z) is a vector of 30 rows and 2 columns (Diffusion vs. distance).

To solve this integral I have tried many strategies such as:

1- Fit an equation to D(z) named F1.
2- Fit another equation to Exponential named F2.
3- Divide F2 into F1 to give us F3 (from library 'pracma').
4- Integrate F3 (from library 'stats').

But my solution result is far away from experimental result.
I think my solution is not correct.

Plz, Could anyone elaborate on how to solve this in R.

Comment: Python and MATLAB are not R, please don't tag spam

Comment: Note that D(z) and G(z) both depend on z hence for all z, the two should have equal number of rows.

Comment: I know that, but I've got nominator in different manner to denominator. In other words, nominator is an output from different equation to denominator.